# How to read and bind column?

Tags: cbind

I have many files, but I can not find how to bind column.

For example, files are followed

```
[1.txt]
ID Score
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4

[2.txt]
ID Score
A  2
B  2
C  3
D  4

[3.txt]
ID Score
A  4
B  4
C  5
D  3
```

I want to make

```
A  1 2 4
B  2 2 4
C  3 3 5
D  4 4 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cbind()` as follows:

```
df_final <- cbind(cbind(df1, df2["Score"]), df3["Score"])
df_final
  ID Score Score Score
1  A     1     2     4
2  B     2     2     4
3  C     3     3     5
4  D     4     4     3
```

Note that if you were trying to match IDs between data frames which did *not* coincidentally have the order you want, then you would be asking more for a database style join.  In this case, R offers the `merge()` function from baseR.

## Demo